# Unable to save field which is @ManyToOne after scaffolding using spring crud application

Tags: java, spring, jsf, javabeans

I am fairly new in **spring/jsf combination** and as a beginner I have faced a lot of issues. First of all the not so big documentation, until now I have managed to surpass some of the issues by trial and error methods but now I am getting really annoyed. I have created a new **web project with MyEclipse and used the Scaffolding Spring CRUD feature which generates 4 layers, the domain object layer, dao , service and component layers**. I have *2 tables, Users and Roles*. The Users table has a column role_id which references the role_id the Roles table. Setting the values for normal columns is not a big deal , **the issue is setting the value of role_id which is a foreign key of the roles table**. I am setting role Id by calling UsersComponent.users.roles.sid and then try to save the user by calling UsersComponent.saveUsers(UsersComponent.users) but it is saving my role_id always as 1. In the meaning time I am seeing that in the log it is setting the role_id as 2,3 or 4.
I have created a page1.xhtml which should add a new user in the database.

Users.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findAllUserss", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByFname", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.fname = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByFnameContaining", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.fname like ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByIsActive", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.isActive = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByLname", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.lname = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByLnameContaining", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.lname like ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByPasswd", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.passwd = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByPasswdContaining", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.passwd like ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByPrimaryKey", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.sid = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersBySid", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.sid = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByUname", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.uname = ?1"),
        //@NamedQuery(name = "findRoleByUname", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.roleId = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findUsersByUnameContaining", query = "select myUsers from Users myUsers where myUsers.uname like ?1") })
@Table(catalog = "alphacrm", schema = "LUT", name = "USERS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "Durandal/al/durandal/com/domain", name = "Users")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private static Logger logger =Logger.getLogger(UsersComponentImpl.class.getName());

    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "SID", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    @XmlElement
    Integer sid;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "UNAME", length = 140, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String uname;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "PASSWD", length = 256)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String passwd;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "FNAME", length = 140)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String fname;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "LNAME", length = 140)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String lname;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    Integer isActive;

    /**
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "SID") })
    @XmlTransient
    Roles roles;

    /*
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    Integer roleId;
    */
    /**
     */
    public void setSid(Integer sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Integer getSid() {
        return this.sid;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getUname() {
        return this.uname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getPasswd() {
        return this.passwd;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getFname() {
        return this.fname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getLname() {
        return this.lname;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setIsActive(Integer isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Integer getIsActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setRoles(Roles roles) {
        logger.info("Entered->setRoles");
        logger.info(roles.toString());

        this.roles = roles;
    }
    /*
    public void RolesId(int a) {
        this.roles.sid = a;
    }
    */

    public Integer getRolesId() {
        return roles.sid;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Roles getRoles() {
        logger.info("Entered->getRoles");
        logger.info(roles.toString());
        return roles;
    }
    /*
    public int getRolesId() {
        return roles.getSid();
    }
*/
    /**
     */
    public Users() {
    }

    /**
     * Copies the contents of the specified bean into this bean.
     *
     */
    public void copy(Users that) {
        setSid(that.getSid());
        setUname(that.getUname());
        setPasswd(that.getPasswd());
        setFname(that.getFname());
        setLname(that.getLname());
        setIsActive(that.getIsActive());
        setRoles(that.getRoles());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a textual representation of a bean.
     *
     */
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        buffer.append("sid=[").append(sid).append("] ");
        buffer.append("uname=[").append(uname).append("] ");
        buffer.append("passwd=[").append(passwd).append("] ");
        buffer.append("fname=[").append(fname).append("] ");
        buffer.append("lname=[").append(lname).append("] ");
        buffer.append("isActive=[").append(isActive).append("] ");

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (int) (prime * result + ((sid == null) ? 0 : sid.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Users))
            return false;
        Users equalCheck = (Users) obj;
        if ((sid == null && equalCheck.sid != null) || (sid != null && equalCheck.sid == null))
            return false;
        if (sid != null && !sid.equals(equalCheck.sid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Roles.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findAllRoless", query = "select myRoles from Roles myRoles"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findRolesByPrimaryKey", query = "select myRoles from Roles myRoles where myRoles.sid = ?1") })
@Table(catalog = "alphacrm", schema = "LUT", name = "ROLES")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "Durandal/al/durandal/com/domain", name = "Roles")
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "Durandal/al/durandal/com/domain")
public class Roles implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "SID", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Id
    @XmlElement
    Integer sid;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", length = 140, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String roleName;
    /**
     */

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 140)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlElement
    String description;

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @XmlElement(name = "", namespace = "")
    java.util.Set<al.durandal.com.domain.Users> userses;

    /**
     */
    public void setSid(Integer sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Integer getSid() {
        return this.sid;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.roleName;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    /**
     */
    public void setUserses(Set<Users> userses) {
        this.userses = userses;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Set<Users> getUserses() {
        if (userses == null) {
            userses = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<al.durandal.com.domain.Users>();
        }
        return userses;
    }

    /**
     */
    public Roles() {
    }

    /**
     * Copies the contents of the specified bean into this bean.
     *
     */
    public void copy(Roles that) {
        setSid(that.getSid());
        setRoleName(that.getRoleName());
        setDescription(that.getDescription());
        setUserses(new java.util.LinkedHashSet<al.durandal.com.domain.Users>(that.getUserses()));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a textual representation of a bean.
     *
     */
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        buffer.append("sid=[").append(sid).append("] ");
        buffer.append("roleName=[").append(roleName).append("] ");
        buffer.append("description=[").append(description).append("] ");

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (int) (prime * result + ((sid == null) ? 0 : sid.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Roles))
            return false;
        Roles equalCheck = (Roles) obj;
        if ((sid == null && equalCheck.sid != null) || (sid != null && equalCheck.sid == null))
            return false;
        if (sid != null && !sid.equals(equalCheck.sid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

UsersServiceImpl.java

```
/**
 * Spring service that handles CRUD requests for Users entities
 * 
 */

@Service("UsersService")
@Transactional
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    private static Logger logger =Logger.getLogger(UsersComponentImpl.class.getName());
    /**
     * DAO injected by Spring that manages Roles entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private RolesDAO rolesDAO;

    /**
     * DAO injected by Spring that manages Users entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private UsersDAO usersDAO;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new UsersServiceImpl.
     *
     */
    public UsersServiceImpl() {
    }

    /**
     * Return a count of all Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public Integer countUserss() {
        return ((Long) usersDAO.createQuerySingleResult("select count(o) from Users o").getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

    /**
     * Delete an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUsers(Users users) {
        usersDAO.remove(users);
        usersDAO.flush();
    }

    /**
     */
    @Transactional
    public Users findUsersByPrimaryKey(Integer sid) {
        return usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sid);
    }

    /**
     */
    @Transactional
    public int findUserByNameAndPassword(String uname,String passw) {
        //return usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sid);

        Set<Users> usersFound = usersDAO.findUsersByUname(uname);
        if (usersFound.size()>0)
        //return "Exist";
        return 1;
        else
        return 2;
        /*
         *      
         * 
         * Users existingUsers = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(users.getSid());

            if (existingUsers != null) {
            if (existingUsers != users) {
                existingUsers.setSid(users.getSid());
                existingUsers.setUname(users.getUname());
                existingUsers.setPasswd(users.getPasswd());
                existingUsers.setFname(users.getFname());
                existingUsers.setLname(users.getLname());
                existingUsers.setIsActive(users.getIsActive());
         */
    }
    public Integer countUsersPass(String uname,String passwd) {
        //return 3;
        return ((Long) usersDAO.createQuerySingleResult("select count(o) from Users o where o.uname= ? and o.passwd= ? ",uname,passwd).getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }


    public Users loadThisUser (String uname){
    //  usersDAO.
        logger.info("Just Entered in loadThisUSer 1");
        Set<Users> users = usersDAO.findUsersByUname(uname);
        Users f= new Users() ;
        for (Iterator<Users> it = users.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            logger.info("Just Entered in loadThisUSer 2");
                  f = it.next();
                  return f;
        }
        logger.info("Just Entered in loadThisUSer 3");
         return f;
    }


    /*
    public Integer findRoleIdByUname(String uname) {
        //return 3;
        //Roles roleHere = new Roles();
        return usersDAO.findRoleByUname(uname);


                //createQuerySingleResult("select count(o) from Users o where o.uname= ? and o.passwd= ? ",uname,passwd).getSingleResult()).intValue();
        //return ((Long) usersDAO.createQuerySingleResult("select o.roles from Users o where o.uname= ? ",uname).getSingleResult()).intValue();
                //return 2;
    }
    */
    /**
     * Save an existing Roles entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public Users saveUsersRoles(Integer sid, Roles related_roles) {
        Users users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sid, -1, -1);
        Roles existingroles = rolesDAO.findRolesByPrimaryKey(related_roles.getSid());

        // copy into the existing record to preserve existing relationships
        if (existingroles != null) {
            existingroles.setSid(related_roles.getSid());
            existingroles.setRoleName(related_roles.getRoleName());
            existingroles.setDescription(related_roles.getDescription());
            related_roles = existingroles;
        } else {
            related_roles = rolesDAO.store(related_roles);
            rolesDAO.flush();
        }

        users.setRoles(related_roles);
        related_roles.getUserses().add(users);
        users = usersDAO.store(users);
        usersDAO.flush();

        related_roles = rolesDAO.store(related_roles);
        rolesDAO.flush();

        return users;
    }

    /**
     * Save an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public void saveUsers(Users users) {
        Users existingUsers = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(users.getSid());

        if (existingUsers != null) {
            if (existingUsers != users) {
                existingUsers.setSid(users.getSid());
                existingUsers.setUname(users.getUname());
                existingUsers.setPasswd(users.getPasswd());
                existingUsers.setFname(users.getFname());
                existingUsers.setLname(users.getLname());
                existingUsers.setIsActive(users.getIsActive());

                logger.info("Just Entered in saveUsers >>"+users.getRoles().toString());

                //existingUsers.setRoles(users.getRoles());
            }
            users = usersDAO.store(existingUsers);
            logger.info("existingUsers --> "+existingUsers.toString());
        } else {

            //users.setRoles(users.getRoles());
            users = usersDAO.store(users);
            logger.info("users --> "+users.toString());
        }
        usersDAO.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Return all Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<Users> findAllUserss(Integer startResult, Integer maxRows) {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<Users>(usersDAO.findAllUserss(startResult, maxRows));
    }

    /**
     * Load an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public Set<Users> loadUserss() {
        return usersDAO.findAllUserss();
    }

    /**
     * Delete an existing Roles entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public Users deleteUsersRoles(Integer users_sid, Integer related_roles_sid) {
        Users users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(users_sid, -1, -1);
        Roles related_roles = rolesDAO.findRolesByPrimaryKey(related_roles_sid, -1, -1);

        users.setRoles(null);
        related_roles.getUserses().remove(users);
        users = usersDAO.store(users);
        usersDAO.flush();

        related_roles = rolesDAO.store(related_roles);
        rolesDAO.flush();

        rolesDAO.remove(related_roles);
        rolesDAO.flush();

        return users;
    }
}
```

UsersComponentImpl

```
/**
 * Spring Component that handles CRUD requests for Users entities
 * 
 */
@Scope("session")
@Component("UsersComponent")
public class UsersComponentImpl implements UsersComponent {

    /**
     * Data type variable that provides CRUD operations for Users entities
     * 
     */
    private Users users;
    private Roles roles;

    /**
     * DAO injected by Spring that manages Users entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private UsersDAO usersDAO;

    /**
     * Service injected by Spring that provides CRUD operations for Users entities
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    /** 
     */
    public UsersComponentImpl() {
    }

    /**
     * Select an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public String selectUsers(Integer sidKey) {
        users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sidKey);

        return "/jsf/users/viewUsers.xhtml";
    }

    /**
     * Create a new Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public String newUsers() {
        users = new Users();

        return "/jsf/users/createUsers.xhtml";
    }

    /**
     * Edit an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public String editUsers(Integer sidKey) {
        users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sidKey);

        return "/jsf/users/editUsers.xhtml";
    }

    /**
     * Getter for variable Users
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    /**
     * Show all Users entities
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<Users> listUserss() {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<Users>(usersService.loadUserss());
    }


    public String returnUserPassw(String uname,String passw){
        int userFound;
        Users userNow= new Users();
        //userFound=usersService.findUserByNameAndPassword(uname, passw);
        //countUsersPass();
        userFound=usersService.countUsersPass(uname, passw);
        if (userFound==1)
        {
            //usersLoaded=usersService.loadThisUser(uname);

            userNow  =usersService.loadThisUser(uname);
            //users.setFname(userNow.getFname());
            users.copy(userNow);

            //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Username and password is correct !"));
            //goHome();
            return "/pages/page1.xhtml";
        }
        else
        {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Fatal!", "Username or password are not correct  !!!"));   
        return "/pages/login.xhtml";
        }
        //if (userFound==0)
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Unedefined Action !!! "+userFound));
    }

    /**
     * Find RoleId by Uname
     */

    public void findRoleIdByUname(String uname){
        //usersService.findRoleIdByUname(uname);


    }
    /**
     * Select the Users entity for display allowing the user to confirm that they would like to delete the entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public String confirmDeleteUsers(Integer sidKey) {
        users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sidKey);

        return "/jsf/users/deleteUsers.xhtml";
    }

    public String logout(){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/pages/login.xhtml";

    }

    /**
     * Save an existing Users entity
     * @return 
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public void saveUsers(Users users) {
        usersService.saveUsers(users);
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "User was added succesfully !!!"));
        //return "/jsf/users/listUserss.xhtml";
    }

    /**
     * Delete an existing Users entity
     * 
     */
    @Transactional
    public String deleteUsers(Integer sidKey) {
        Users users = usersDAO.findUsersByPrimaryKey(sidKey);
        usersService.deleteUsers(users);
        return "/jsf/users/listUserss.xhtml";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        users = new Users();
        roles = new Roles();
        //roles = new Roles();
        //users.setSid(3);
    }


}
```

page1.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="metadata">
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form prependId="false">
        <!-- 
        <p:button  value="#{usersmsgs['navigation.back']}" >
            <f:param value="#{usersmsgs['navigation.back']}" action="/jsf/users/listUserss.xhtml" name="backButton"/>
        </p:button>
 -->
            <p:panel header="#{usersmsgs['users.title']} Details"  style="width:50%">


                <h:panelGrid id="detail" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.sid.title']}:*" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_sid" value="#{UsersComponent.users.sid}" required="true" label="users_sid" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.uname.title']}:" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_uname" value="#{UsersComponent.users.uname}" required="false" label="users_uname" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.passwd.title']}:" />
                            <p:password id="password" value="#{UsersComponent.users.passwd}" required="false" label="users_passwd" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.fname.title']}:" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_fname" value="#{UsersComponent.users.fname}" required="false" label="users_fname" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.lname.title']}:" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_lname" value="#{UsersComponent.users.lname}" required="false" label="users_lname" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.isactive.title']}:" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_isactive" value="#{UsersComponent.users.isActive}" required="false" label="users_isactive" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['users.roles.title']}:" />
                            <p:inputText id="users_roles" value="#{UsersComponent.users.roles.sid}" required="false" label="users_roles" />




                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" style="margin-right:20px;" value="#{usersmsgs['navigation.save']}" action="#{UsersComponent.saveUsers(UsersComponent.users)}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>


        </h:form>

    <ui:debug hotkey="y"> </ui:debug>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

console.log

```
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:27 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[4] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:27 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:27 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[4] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.service.UsersServiceImpl saveUsers
INFO: users --> sid=[2124] uname=[panddwi3ed] passwd=[] fname=[fnamed] lname=[lnamed] isActive=[1] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system] 
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: Entered->getRoles
Mar 16, 2015 11:27:28 AM al.durandal.com.domain.Users getRoles
INFO: sid=[3] roleName=[Administrator] description=[Administrator of the system]
```

Comment: You are using `@Transactional` in Spring managed beans on the web tier which is not required. You do not seem to have set `role_id` while persisting `Users` in the `saveUsers()` method in the `UsersServiceImpl` class. An explicit flush is not required, when you use declarative transactions as implied by statements like `usersDAO.flush();` and there is a lot of irrelevant code noise. If persisting an entity is the only issue then, the question is completely unrelated to JSF and in that case, you may want to remove the whole JSF noise.

Comment: Hi , I added existingUsers.setRoles(users.getRoles()); in USersServiceImpl.java and the result is the same. All these classes were generated by Spring and not by me. Is there any other easier way to integrate JSF with backend than spring?